# capture keyboard character as string

Tags: mfc

Under PreTranslateMessage() check the keydown event and capture the same in some variable,

Keydown event capture the value for single character only,
But I would like to capture certain no of character and search the same string inside list control

I am able to search a single character, but for multiple character, need some way to capture the same such as I can create the search string such as xyz and can search the same in list control , but as soon as I press x, it is getting searched.

Please suggest the approach to solve the same.

Comment: Better revise the UI spec, ie use an edit-box (add a "Search" label next to it) and search into the list-control as the text changes. Otherwise you will have to keep track of the keystrokes yourself, eg store them in some structure and maintain it, as well as provide a mechanism for clearing it. I think the edit-box is a lot better, as the user will be able to see the string being searched.

Comment: You are confusing different concepts. Keyboard messages pass (virtual) key codes. A string consists of characters. Often times, a key maps to a character, but that is not always the case. Irrespective of that, you are probably trying to reinvent, what's already in the platform. Please ask about the problem you are ultimately trying to solve, rather than your solution. This is known as the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Constantine Georgiou: I had implemented the edit box feature succesfully, i.e enter the search string in edit box and search the same in list control.
Now I am trying to remove the edit box and search the string I entered from keyboard , so when my list control has the focus, I type any search string and if the same exist in the control, it will highlighted.

Comment: IInspectable: I had placed one edit box which contain the string need to be searched, and the list control filled with some data, if I found the string entered in the edit box, i highlight the same in list control, Now I don't want to use edit box for entering the search string.Now, what ever the user type from the keyboard, certain n no of characters which make a search string, that I want to search in the list control